# Modern web pages that can be scrolled using the arrow keys (how)?

Tags: plugins

Recently i've seen lots of modern web pages that can be scrolled using the arrow keys, like this one: http://www.thinkingforaliving.org/topics/curated I think they use jQuery (is not flash). Does anyone knows a good jQuery plugin (or other library) that does this?

Comment: They probably use **Javascript** (as opposed to Flash), not necessarily jQuery!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a fan of the [jQuery hotkeys plugin](http://github.com/tzuryby/jquery.hotkeys). Just capture the up and down and/or left and right and use jQuery methods like `.scrollTo()` for the desired effect.